# Want minimal DTD & headers for hidden iframe

Tags: html, iframe, header

I'm using a hidden iframe to sandbox some javascript functions. I'd like to know which headers are recommended to include in the iframe. I'm looking to cut anything not needed: the title, meta tags, etc.

1) Is it advisable to simply use `<html><body></body></html>` since the document contains nothing other than javascript? (Are there any gotchas I should be aware of in doing this?)

2) if I cut out language and encoding declarations and return utf-8 characters from the iframe to the parent window (which has the headers below), will those characters be displayed correctly?

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='eng' lang='en'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<title>New Site</title>
<meta name='Description' content='Website Under Construction' />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML5 instead of XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <title></title>
    <script>...</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Could I drop the <head> with <title> tags and move the <script> into the body? Or could I drop the <title> and <body> while leaving the script in the head? I want the smallest footprint possible for my iscript. Thanks.

Comment: @skibulk: If you want it to be valid, you need a `<title>`.  If you don't need to to be valid, you can use nothing but a `<script>` tag and it will probably still work.

Comment: However, my original answer was needlessly verbose; this edit is much shorter and still valid